# Preprocessor Macro Translation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

In the .NET Core CLR source code, I found the following macro definition:

```
#define CORECLR_HOSTING_API(function, ...) \
  extern "C" int function(__VA_ARGS__); \
  typedef int (*function##_ptr)(__VA_ARGS__)

CORECLR_HOSTING_API(coreclr_shutdown,
            void* hostHandle,
            unsigned int domainId);
```

The comments say that this defines a function prototype and a function pointer. Is anyone able to "translate" what the non-macro version of this would look like? That is to say, what would this look like if it was NOT wrapped in the macro? The "*function##_ptr" part is confusing me...

Comment: If it says `extern "C" …`, then the code is intended for C++ and not for a pure C compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The `##` operator is concatenation, used here because `function_ptr` is a valid identifier, so the preprocessor wouldn't know to replace the `function` part of it. The result of preprocessing, then, is:

```
extern "C" int coreclr_shutdown(void* hostHandle, unsigned int domainId);
typedef int (*coreclr_shutdown_ptr)(void* hostHandle, unsigned int domainId);
```

(modulo whitespace changes I've made for readability)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there are compiler options which allow to see the proprocessor output of statements. If not, there always is [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kh0vVj), in which you can use `-E` option with `gcc` compiler to see (newline added by me):

```
extern "C" int coreclr_shutdown(void* hostHandle, unsigned int domainId); 
typedef int (*coreclr_shutdown_ptr)(void* hostHandle, unsigned int domainId)
```

The `##` in macro expansion means concatenation. So the `function ## _ptr` means to concatenate the string behind `function` (it's macro argument) with the string (literal) `_ptr`. It's typically for example to:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b
CONCAT(abc, def) // will be translated by preprocessor into abcdef
```

Comment: Strange that godbolt excludes the semicolon after the macro invocation. Regardless, it seems like a nice resource.

Comment: @CraigMeier that is because Godbolt thinks it is printing assembly with -E and hence it treats everything after the first `;` as a comment and removes any more `;` Click on the green tick to see the exact command. It has a `-S` implicitly added

Comment: Being able to see that in gcc is useful, I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux with build-essential packages, allowing me to test at least minimal cross-platform support. Thanks for the tip!